# My decoder isn's seeing the one of my JSON objects in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I'm trying use Codable protocol to decode JSON from the FAA's website. It seems to work fine with some of the sub sections of the JSON but no matter what I try I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have the section that is being read setup exactly as the section that is being ignored.

Here is my Codable model:

```
struct Runway: Codable {
    var type: String
    var features: [Features]
    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "type"
        case features = "features"
    }
    struct Features: Codable {
        var type: String
        var properties: Properties
        var geometry: Geometry
        enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type = "type"
            case properties = "properties"
            case geometry = "geometry"
        }
        struct Properties: Codable {
            var objectID: Int?
            var globalID: String?
            var airportID: String?
            var designator: String?
            var length: Int?
            var width: Int?
            var lightActivity: Int?
            var lightInt: String?

            private enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case objectID = "OBJECTID"
                case globalID = "GLOBAL_ID"
                case airportID = "AIRPORT_ID"
                case designator = "DESIGNATOR"
                case length = "LENGTH"
                case width = "WIDTH"
                case lightActivity = "LIGHTACTV"
                case lightInt = "LIGHTINTNS"
            }
        }
        struct Geometry: Codable {
            var type: String
            var coordinates: [[[Double]]]
            enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case type = "type"
                case coordinates = "coordinates"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the first couple JSON elements: (Sorry for the formatting, no matter what I try I cant get the JSON to look correct. But Im getting everything but the Properties Struct. The Properties Struct is being returned nil.

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "OBJECTID":3001,
            "GLOBAL_ID":"B5559C52-205D-479D-800A-C462015FCCE8",
            "AIRPORT_ID":"98D2CC5B-EBC9-4901-8B72-AB5596FFDD02",
            "DESIGNATOR":"13",
            "LENGTH":3499,
            "WIDTH":77,
            "DIM_UOM":"FT",
            "COMP_CODE":"ASPH",
            "LIGHTACTV":2,
            "LIGHTINTNS":"LIM",
            "AK_LOW":0,
            "AK_HIGH":0,
            "US_LOW":1,
            "US_HIGH":0,
            "US_AREA":0,
            "PACIFIC":0,
            "Shape__Area":0.00000278998996340473,
            "Shape__Length":0.0235944263922133
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -91.4991881305143,
                     43.5930572596937,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -91.4993937775553,
                     43.5929079896572,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -91.5087273920645,
                     43.599699649116,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -91.5085217450235,
                     43.5998489351524,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -91.4991881305143,
                     43.5930572596937,
                     0
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "OBJECTID":3002,
            "GLOBAL_ID":"82E74ABD-6CCA-4505-8B1A-468A5A1B4058",
            "AIRPORT_ID":"18DFA099-66A1-4AE5-B2F8-C62052139996",
            "DESIGNATOR":"16",
            "LENGTH":4001,
            "WIDTH":75,
            "DIM_UOM":"FT",
            "COMP_CODE":"ASPH",
            "LIGHTACTV":2,
            "LIGHTINTNS":"LIM",
            "AK_LOW":0,
            "AK_HIGH":0,
            "US_LOW":1,
            "US_HIGH":0,
            "US_AREA":0,
            "PACIFIC":0,
            "Shape__Area":0.00000321253134576419,
            "Shape__Length":0.0235103894432249
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -93.2617071279774,
                     45.5523006585432,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -93.2619863670487,
                     45.5522388825147,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -93.2666779488979,
                     45.5627046006791,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -93.2663986638266,
                     45.5627663877077,
                     0
                  ],
                  [
                     -93.2617071279774,
                     45.5523006585432,
                     0
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The function I'm using to get it is:func loadDataFromJSON(){
        let airportURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Runways", withExtension: "json")!
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let result = try decoder.decode(Runway.self, from: Data(contentsOf: airportURL))
            
            print(result.features as Any)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Copy and paste the full JSON here. Format it as code. And you now what... try [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) if you don't feel like type

Comment: you sure, its 388525 lines of JSON

Comment: Look like a good job for [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io). Have you given it a try?

Comment: OMG!!! Dude... the quicktype link!! haha thats the greatest thing ive seen all day! thanks so much. Bookmarking that. where were you 7 hours ago!!!

Comment: Although, im still curious what I was messing up?

Comment: Without seeing your error message it's impossible to tell. But if the JSON is that deeply nested, you may have got the internal structures wrong, or that a key is nillable but you didn't think about it as such.

Comment: Thanks again! it definitely makes dealing with the FAA easier.

Comment: you have to append "]}" to you JSON string in question to be valid

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy you have only to replace `codingKeys` with `CodingKeys`.